# what is the equivalent of all_tables and all_tab_columns in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to run oracle query

```
SELECT OWNER,  
       TABLE_NAME 
FROM ALL_TABLES;

SELECT COLUMN_NAME, 
       DATA_TYPE, 
       DATA_LENGTH, 
       NULLABLE, 
       COLUMN_ID, 
       DATA_PRECISION, 
       DATA_SCALE 
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
```

in postgresql but it is not able to excute that because PostgreSQL doesn't have ALL_TAB_COLUMNS  and ALL_TABLES

Can any body suggest what is the equivalent query of that

Answer (score 20):

ALL_TABLES is equivalent to the (ANSI standard) view `information_schema.tables`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-tables.html

ALL_TAB_COLUMNS is equivalent to the (ANSI standard) view `information_schema.columns`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-columns.html

Comment: Going through a manual would be much more work than looking it up on stackoverflow. I like very much, that Amrin asked that question and you replied. Thx both of you

Answer (score 3):

information_schema.columns lacks the Num_Distinct and Num_Nulls information columns.

Comment: that's right, that made the thing! 
select distinct(table_name) from information_schema.columns